# Given three $2 \times 2$ invertible matrices $A, B, C,$ solve for $A$ given $A = BAB^{T} + C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given three $2 \times 2$ matrices (A,B,C), whose inverses exist, I need to solve for A using the following equation:

$A = BAB^{T} + C$

I can't seem to isolate $A$ from $B$ . Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't solve this using matrix multiplication alone.  However, with [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), we can rewrite this as
$$
A - B^TAB = C\\
{\rm vec}[A - B^TAB] = {\rm vec}(C)\\
I_{4 \times 4} {\rm vec}(A) - (B^T \otimes B^T) {\rm vec}(A) = {\rm vec}(C)\\
(I_{4 \times 4} - B^T \otimes B^T) {\rm vec}(A) = {\rm vec}(C)
$$
and this is a linear system on $4$ variables that can be solved in the usual way.  The matrix $(I_{4 \times 4} - B^T \otimes B^T)$ will be invertible if and only if $B$ has no (possibly repeating) pair of eigenvalues satisfying $\lambda_1\lambda_2 = 1$. Since $B$ has size $2$, this means that the matrix will be invertible if and only if $\det(B) \neq 1$ and $B$ has neither $1$ nor $-1$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: Interestingly: whenever this series converges, we can write
$$
C = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (B^k)^T A B^k
$$
where we take $B^0 = I$.

Comment: Just noticed the second term in the third line should be $(B \otimes B)vec(A)$. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Matt the transposes should be there. Is there a reason you think that they shouldn't?

Comment: @Matt ah, I used $B^TAB$ instead of $BAB^T$.  So yes, you're right.  $B \otimes B$ gives you the correct result.